# Using correlated subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Assume 2 tables t_left and t_right indexed on column val1.
They do have 100000 records each randomized on val1.
I have 2 options to extract records from t_left not present in t_right:

```
1.SELECT *
FROM t_left o
WHERE o.val1 not in (Select val1 
                              FROM t_right h) 

2.SELECT *
FROM t_left o
WHERE o.val1 not in (Select val1 
                              FROM t_right h 
                              where h.val1 = o.val1)
```

Surprisingly,I see the same execution plan for both approaches.
Are these just syntactic quirks;or they do have unique appropriate used-cases?
I am using sql server 2008.

Comment: Can you post an execution plan of both the queries.

Comment: You could also use EXCEPT: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Comment: Please note that this post is explicitly to understand the difference between the above.I know there are several other ways to achieve this result.

Comment: @NickyvV:Question is why execution plans are different not approach of writing queries. Other way out could be LEFT JOIN as well.

Comment: IUnknown: It's hard to believe on same execution plan with both tables having multiple records. Can you post execution plan of both the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can return different results if  `t_right` contains `NULL`.

`NOT IN (x, y, NULL)` always returns an empty set but the equality predicate implicitly excludes any `NULL` from  `t_right`.

- [SQL Fiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30581) (no results as null preserved)
- [SQL Fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30580)

Additionally they can return different results if  `t_left` contains `NULL` and `t_right` is non empty.

`NULL NOT IN (...)`

is never true except if `(...)` is an empty set so any `NULL`s in the left hand side are only preserved if `t_right` is totally empty or by the second query.

If neither column is nullable both queries will have the same semantics and likely the same plan.

Comment: +1 - That is true, but conceptually they are the same (assuming you eliminate null values)

Comment: @Martin: Why would an execution plan be same if both of the tables have multiple records. As inner query will be executed everytime for an outer query.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta - SQL is declarative not imperative. You can't assume that query syntax will reflect execution plans. The query optimiser has tons of transformation rules to recognize when things are semantically the same and, e.g. decorrelate sub queries. The inner query will not necessarily be executed everytime for an outer query at all. This is an anti semi join operator in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the two query plans are the same (at least at the level of the execution plan) is because the two queries have a certain equivalency.

Take the first query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_left o
WHERE o.val1 not in (Select val1 FROM t_right h);
```

One way that SQL Server can execute this query is by using the index on `t_right.val1`.  In other words, the query gets executed as:  "Look up each `val1` in `t_left` in the index on `t_right.val1`.  If you don't find it, then do accept the record."

The second query adds the correlation to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_left o
WHERE o.val1 not in (Select val1 FROM t_right h WHERE h.val1 = o.val1);
```

Guess what?  *Exactly* the same execution approach can work for this query.  The correlation just makes the index lookup more explicit.

By the way, there is another way to express this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_left o
WHERE not exists (Select val1 FROM t_right h WHERE h.val1 = o.val1);
```

My guess is that this would also have the same execution plan.

Martin's comment is very interesting, because the two queries are not the same, unless `val1` is the primary key in `t_right`.

Comment: Don't follow the significance you think PK has here? Other than the `NOT NULL` caveat I already mentioned. Duplicates in t_right. are surely irrelevant. `2 NOT IN (2,2)` and `2 NOT IN (2)` are the same.

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . If it is a primary key, then it can't be `NULL`, and the optimizer could take advantage of this fact.  Actually, it might just be declared `NOT NULL`, I was thinking only of the index when I wrote that.